# low fps while performing real time hand detection in expo react native

Tags: react-native, performance, expo, detection, tensorflow.js

my camera is lagging and giving me low fps and also the detection is not accurate while performing realtime detection in expo react native. I tried the same thing in react.js and it run smoothly.

I want the code to detect asl.
I am using https://github.com/Adamo-O/Handle/blob/master/src/App.tsx github repo as a reference
please help me to fix my issue.

code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Camera, CameraType } from "expo-camera";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import * as handpose from "@tensorflow-models/handpose";
// @ts-ignore
import * as fp from "fingerpose";
import Handsigns from "../../components/handsigns";
import { Signimage, Signpass } from "../../components/handimage";
import { cameraWithTensors } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
import { Switch } from "tamagui";

const imageWidth = 224;
const imageHeight = 224;
const imageChannels = 3;
const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);
  const [model, setModel] = useState(null);
  const [ShowCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false);
  const [sign, setSign] = useState(null);


  async function runHandpose() {
    try {
      const net = await handpose.load();
      if (net) {
        setModel(net);
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to load handpose model");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading handpose model:", error);
    }
  }


  async function handleCameraStream(images) {
    console.log(cameraRef.current)
    const loop = async () => {

      let nextImageTensor = images.next().value;
      //console.log(nextImageTensor)
      if(nextImageTensor){



      if (model !== null) {
        const hand = await model.estimateHands(nextImageTensor);

        if (hand.length > 0) {
          console.log("done")
          const GE = new fp.GestureEstimator([
            Handsigns.aSign,
            Handsigns.bSign,
          ]);
          const estimatedGestures = await GE.estimate(hand[0].landmarks, 4.5);

          if (
            estimatedGestures.gestures !== undefined &&
            estimatedGestures.gestures.length > 0
          ) {
            const confidence = estimatedGestures.gestures.map((p) => p.score ? p.score : p.confidence);
            const maxConfidence = confidence.indexOf(
              Math.max.apply(null, confidence)
            );
           
          }
        }
        
      }
      tf.dispose(nextImageTensor);
  }
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    loop();
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    runHandpose();
  }, []);

  function togglecam(){
    setShowCamera(!ShowCamera)
  }
  let textureDims = { height: 224, width: 224 };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Switch size="$2.5" onCheckedChange={togglecam}>
        <Switch.Thumb animation="bouncy" />
      </Switch>


      {ShowCamera && (
      <TensorCamera
        ref={cameraRef}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        type={CameraType.front}
        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
        resizeHeight={imageHeight}
        resizeWidth={imageWidth}
        ratio='4:3'
        resizeDepth={imageChannels}
        onReady={handleCameraStream} // Fixed function name
        autorender={true}
        useCustomShadersToResize={false}
      />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  overlayCanvas: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  detectedGesture: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 16,
    left: 16,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 8,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  detectedGestureText: {
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  detectedGestureImage: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  },
  cameraToggleButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 16,
    right: 16,
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
    borderRadius: 8,
  },
});
```